# Nestjs Typeorm postgresql Error No repository '***' was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

This issue was triggered when converting from a monolith to a monorepo using nestjs cli (nest app). surprisingly it returns an error with the repository like so.
[image: error encounter]

the files:

auth/auth.module.ts

```
Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
      username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DATABASE_DB,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

auth/user/users.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      UsersRepository,
      UserDeviceRepository,
      UserLocationRepository,
      UserOTPRepository,
      UserCredentialRepository,
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [UserService, JwtStrategy, OtpService],
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [JwtStrategy, PassportModule],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

auth/user/repository/user.repository.ts

```
@EntityRepository(Users)
export class UsersRepository extends Repository<Users> {
  async createCustomer(
    signUpCredentialsDto: SignUpCredentialsDto,
  ): Promise<Users> {
    const { phone } = signUpCredentialsDto;

    const customer = this.create({
      phone: phone,
      is_phone_verified: false,
      is_email_verified: false,
      is_complete_profile: false,
      is_suspended: false,
      access_level: UserAccessLevel.CUSTOMER,
    });

    try {
      await this.save(customer);
      return customer;
    } catch (error) {
      // duplicate user (phone,email)
      if (error.code === '23505') {
        throw new ConflictException('Phone / email already exists');
      } else {
        console.error(error);
        throw new InternalServerErrorException();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

auth/user/entity/user.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
export class Users {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id_user: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  name: string;

  @Column('varchar', { length: 15, unique: true })
  phone: string;

  @Column({ unique: true, nullable: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ type: 'date', nullable: true })
  birth_date: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  occupation: string;

  @Column()
  is_phone_verified: boolean;

  @Column()
  is_email_verified: boolean;

  @Column()
  is_complete_profile: boolean;

  @Column()
  is_suspended: boolean;

  @Column()
  access_level: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  gender: string;

  @OneToMany((_type) => UserDevice, (device) => device.user, { eager: false })
  device: UserDevice[];

  @OneToMany((_type) => UserLocation, (location) => location.user, {
    eager: false,
  })
  location: UserLocation[];

  @OneToOne((_type) => UserCredentials, (credential) => credential.user)
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  credential: UserCredentials;
}
```

What's surprising is that in monolith it still runs properly.
I've been reviewing this for 2 days and looking over the internet with no luck.
Really appreciate any help i can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide the path for entities in  Typeorm module like this

```
TypeormModule.forRoot({
    entities: [join(__dirname, '**', '*.entities.{js,ts}')],
    /* rest of config */
  })
```

Comment: tried this, and even mentioning each entities in the array does not work. but for some reason, my second attempt of cloning the monolith project and running the same CLI `nest g app` works. so i will put this case to a close. i honestly have no idea what went wrong in the first one.

thankyou for the help!